# No module named Crypto error when trying to calculate / verify signature

Tags: python, cryptography

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5

message = "I want this stream signed"
digest = SHA256.new()
digest.update(message)

# Read shared key from file
private_key = False
with open ("private_key.pem", "r") as myfile:
private_key = RSA.importKey(myfile.read())

# Load private key and sign message
signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(private_key)
sig = signer.sign(digest)

# Load public key and verify message
verifier = PKCS1_v1_5.new(private_key.publickey())
verified = verifier.verify(digest, sig)
assert verified, 'Signature verification failed'
print('Successfully verified message')
```

I have been trying example code but it makes a mistake when i upload Crypto libraries . I'm using Python 3.6

The error is:
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'

Comment: You presumably didn't install the library. `pip install pycrypto`

Comment: I tried and result ->  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.12.25827\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: Command "c:\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Samsung\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kwts9qw0\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ugj85xax\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kwts9qw0\pycrypto\

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full traceback so we can read it rather than posting in comments. Are you using Visual Studio as an editor? From what I can see of the error, I'm not sure whether it's an issue that the library can't be compiled on your system or you tried to execute that command in python

Comment: Looks like this is a current open bug: [Error while attempting to install PyCrypto on Python 3.6 x64](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/issues/218) There are a few workaround fixes in the comments at the bottom of that page